# PHP auto create seo friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have PHP url for show content for each page in language like :

category:

```
articles
gallery
page
books
....
```

URL:

```
http://localhost/cms/load.php?page=articles&id=1&title=this-is-a-title.html&lang=ru
http://localhost/cms/load.php?page=page&id=10&title=this-is-a-page-title.html&lang=ru
```

In action i need to auto rewrite url to seo friendly url like this :

```
http://localhost/cms/ru/articles/1/this-is-a-title.html
http://localhost/cms/ru/page/10/this-is-a-page-title.html
```

load.php

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? safeGET($_GET['page']) : null;
$id   = isset($_GET['id'])   ? safeGET($_GET['id'])   : null;
if ($page=='articles') { include 'article.php'; } elseif { ... }
```

how do can i generate this `URL` with `PHP` (Preference without mod-rewrite)?! OR with `.htaccess and PHP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in the following way:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cms/
RewriteRule ^([a-z,A-Z]+)/([a-z,A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z,A-Z,0-9]+)$ ./load.php?page=$2&id=$3&title=$4&lang=$1 [L,NC]
```

This way your load.php file doesn't need to change and can accept the seo urls.

You will need to change the code that creates your URLs, if you update your answer how your URL's are currently being generated we can help you with that too.

Comment: cms is subfolder in localhost xammp and u need to change `RewriteBase /cms/`if cms install in subfolder. `ru` language need to show after root directory. this not work perfectly

Comment: When I redirect from within load.php, the resulting URL is no longer pretty - Apache handles the redirect to load.php but the forwarding redirect from there still has a dirty url, as it is created from within the php script, so the resulting page is still `page.php?id=1234` in the browsers url bar. How do I get around that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a routing class. You'd add a htaccess file that rewrites everything to a index.php file, then you'd control all the routing within PHP.

AltoRouter is my favorite one https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter. It's inspired by Ruby's Sinatra, but if you Google "PHP routing class" you can find  many more similar classes to use for routing your urls.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Don't see why you're signaling my answer out. The other answers here including links did not do that also. My answer isn't link only, I just mentioned using a routing class. If you Google PHP routing class you'll find plenty of them. They all work the same way generally and I was just mentioning my favorite one that I currently use.

Answer (score 1):

save yourself some pain and use a routing framework (i.e. http://www.slimframework.com/)

though *creation* of the `seo friendly urls` (also called slugs) is not included

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find two useful guides i used to understand how .htacces works. There are a lot of good example, I hope it helps:

**First guide:**
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757

**Second guide:**
https://www.branded3.com/blog/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/